# Problem with gnome-shell 3.10 in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: gnome

I installed gnome-shell 3.10 in ubuntu 13.10 but have several problems:

1. I couldn't decrease brightness with fn+f5 but I could increase that with fn+f6.
2. I couldn't set alt+shift to change keyboard layout.(my system is up to date)
3. Installing gnome-shell 3.10 also caused a problem for unity desktop in unity desktop there isn't mouse arrow!

please help me to solve them. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your 1. and 2. questions, but for the 3.it helped me to switch the display manager to gdm. Therefore first logout, switch to terminal by [Strg+Alt+F1], login and enter:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Then restart gdm:

```
sudo services gdm restart
```

Now, I hope some things are better now. Good Luck.